# How to delete a row from table view IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to delete a row from table view without using the below data source method. How to do it?

```
- (void) tableView : (UITableView *)tableView 
commitEditingStyle : (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
 forRowAtIndexPath : (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Delete the row from the source (`NSArray`), then reload the tableView. I think this would be work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)?

(I've linked Apple's documentation linked for you).

@Scar's idea is also good, but that will refresh the entire table and that might be a bit disruptive to the user if they're scrolled to the bottom of the table and the refresh takes them to the top.

Comment: You have to create it. If you know the row, it's as easy as ["`NSIndexPath * myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: rowNumber inSection: sectionNumber];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSIndexPath/indexPathForRow:inSection:) (and I've linked this documentation for you, too).

Comment: its not fully correct your app will not read the right rows from the backing datasource.

Comment: You're right about this, @stackmonster.  Not only does the row have to be removed from the table, it has to be removed from the backing data source as well.  +1 to you!

Answer (score 3):

Not quite that simple, you have to do this atomically with a UITableView

```
[_tableView beginUpdates]; // <-- pretty important

long selectedRow = _tableView.selectedRow;

[_tableView removeRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:selectedRow] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideUp];

//then remove your object from the array
[((NSMutableArray*) _searchResults) removeObjectAtIndex:selectedRow];

[_tableView endUpdates];
```

This prevents delegate methods from being called while the array is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the row from your model and call `-deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.